# Android remove values from Spinner

Tags: android, spinner

I have a spinner populated from a cursor using SimpleCursorAdapter
I want to delete some values from this adapter depending on a variable
I try something like this but doesn't work fine

```
SimpleCursorAdapter toListAdapter = new SimpleCursorAdapter(MoreTicketSalesActivity.this, R.layout.generic_spinneritem, cursor, column,
        viewIds) {


@Override
public void bindView(View view, Context context, Cursor cursor) {
    super.bindView(view, context, cursor);
        if (cursor.getLong(3) < session.getStopIndex()) {
            view.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
        }
    }
};
```

Please help me

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So i find a solution who is just perfect for me

```
TextView textView = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.spinner_item_name);
int index = cursor.getInt(cursor.getColumnIndex("index"));
String name = cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex("name"));
textView.setText(name);
if (index <= this.index) {
    textView.setTextColor(Color.LTGRAY);
    textView.setClickable(true);
} else {
    textView.setTextColor(Color.BLACK);
    textView.setClickable(false);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

First of All you check value of your variable and get location of items to be deleted from the cursor.

1. Then remove those values from Cursor ( by remove(position of value) or etc ).
2. Then use toListAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();

Comment: How to remove values from cursor ... cursor is readonly (as i know). The cursor comes with values and is correct. Perhaps i must explain more. I have 2 spinners populated with the same cursor. Is Stop Station Names. If i select something in From spinner then in To spinner i must remove all the values who passed From selected stop.

Comment: why don't you create String array or List and use it.

Comment: Because in the cursor i have id, index, name. I need all this values. I can make a list List<MyObject> but i have difficulties rendering the spinner.

Comment: Try this:Create a new Database and in table put your all data.And after checking your variable value update table and generate new cursor & use it.

Comment: If you read my comment above i say i have 2 spinners. Depending on selection of first spinner the second spinner is filtered. If i make like you suggest adding every time values in database i think will be time consuming.

Comment: OK then Tell me what is the difficulty with using List<MyObject>.

Comment: One more thing you can do, use only List<String> (for From spinner & To spinner).Then you can easily manipulate values of second spinner (To Spinner)  and after making selection from both spinner get all other info (like id, index, name) by querying Cursor.